# Wait for Element ID before proceeding (long wait) Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is this the proper way to wait for an Element ID to be loaded?

I click a submit button, this page will load from 5-30 minutes.. Once it's done I need to repeat the process. My view is that I should just wait for an ID to be present. Is this the best way to do it?

```
Wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 999).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "files"))) #Find element by text
print(wait.text) #Display text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices for Selenium today recommend using a framework that simplifies the code needed for waiting. For example, waiting for an element in [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) with the `Driver()` format may look like this:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
driver.get("https://example.com")
driver.wait_for_element("h1", timeout=100)
driver.highlight("h1")
driver.quit()
```

With an ID:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
driver.get("https://developer.mozilla.org/")
driver.wait_for_element("#content h1", timeout=100)
driver.highlight("#content h1")
driver.quit()
```

There's a lot of posts on Stack Overflow that mention `WebDriverWait` and `EC.visibility_of_element_located`, etc, but those lead to very long & messy test scripts. The modern way involves keeping things clean by using frameworks that simplify things.